# Regular Expression to find incomplete Java assertions

Tags: java, regex, assert, regex-lookarounds

In Java you can use assert() statements like these:

```
// ok
assertFalse(",", Boolean.FALSE);
assertFalse("", Boolean.FALSE);
assertFalse("ab" + "cd" + "de", Boolean.FALSE);
assertFalse(errorMessage, Boolean.FALSE);
assertFalse(errorMessage.toString(), Boolean.FALSE);
assertFalse("Assertion failed, because: " + errorMessage.toString(), Boolean.FALSE);

// nok    
assertFalse(Boolean.FALSE);
assertFalse(expectedMessage.endsWith("ab,cd"));
```

From a code style point-of-view we define asserts as *OK* if the assert has an assertion error message as first argument and *NOK = Not OK* if it is absent.

Having said that, I need a regular expression that searches for asserts that do not have a comma , in their round brackets (). Commas inside string constants (delimited by quotes ") must also be excluded as they lead to false positives.

I ended up with this regular expression which obviously does not take quotes into account as I cannot get those working for me:

```
assert(False|NotNull|Null|True)\(\s*.*(?!,).*\s*\);
```

We also use `assertEquals` and `assertSame` which need three commas but this could be a separate regex.

Any ideas or solutions on that? How can we find assertFalse() statements that only have one argument?

Please don't come up with any other tools or plugins as they are forbidden to use. Just pure regex. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/5sPoSC/1)

```
assert(?:False|(?:Not)?Null|True)\([^(),]*(?:\([^)]*\))*\);
```

- `assert` Match this literally
- `(?:False|(?:Not)?Null|True)` Match either `False`, `NotNull`, `Null`, or `True`
- `\(` Match `(` literally
- `[^(),]*` Match any number of any character except `(`, `)` or `,`
- `(?:\([^)]*\))*` Match the following any number of times

  - Match `(`, followed by any character except `)` any number of times, then by `)`
- `\);` Match `);` literally

To properly catch these instances, however, you're better to write a parser because Java's regex engine doesn't allow recursion or balancing. This means a regex (like the one I provided) will break on nested `()` within `()` such as `assertFalse(something(somethingelse()));`. If you don't care about these cases, then you can use regex, otherwise, I'd advise you to create a parser or use another method.

Comment: Any reason why this was downvoted? I'd like to improve it if you could point me in the right direction :) It does get the answer the OP is looking for and they did specify a *pure regex* solution was necessary.

Comment: My guess is because of suggesting to use a parser. My first thought was "thats way too complex, there are many tools that can just find the usage of the forbidden method". Then I read "Please don't come up with any other tools or plugins as they are forbidden to use." (Which I find strange, as tools are often clearly the way to go here). In that case, a simple parser wouldn't be a bad idea at all.

Comment: @NickL thanks, I took your advise and moved it to the end :)

Comment: Maybe move the parser suggestion to the end? For downvoters that only read the first line. The more I think about it, the worse regex looks to me for this.. so many ways to break it. Escaped characters, comma's in a string, comma's in the right hand side. Etc.

Comment: The downvote is due to suggesting a regex to parse code. That's why I do not answer such questions, usually, when there is a high chance there are dedicated code-parsing libraries.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew fair enough. User specifed *pure regex*, so I thought it might be fair to answer this question in such a way. I completely understand your downvote though, thanks for letting me know, I do appreciate the feedback :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew gotcha, well thanks for the feedback anyway, it's still appreciated.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments, they are much appreciated.